# unable out figure out error in below program

Tags: c++, algorithm, brute-force

I was solving a problem https://codeforces.com/contest/489/problem/B

Its a simple brute force approach,In my terminal when i am giving input

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
vector <int> b;
vector <int> g;
int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int a;
        cin >> a;
        b.push_back(a);
    }
    int m;
    cin >> m;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        int a;
        cin >> a;
        g.push_back(a);
    }
    sort(b.begin(), b.end());
    sort(g.begin(), g.end());
    int ans = 0;


    bool visited[10000];
    memset(visited, sizeof(visited), false);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            if(!visited[j])
            if (abs(b[i] - g[j]) <= 1) {
                visited[j] = true;
                ans++;
                break;
            }
        }

    }
    cout << ans;

}
```

4

1 4 6 2

5

5 1 5 7 9

I am getting correct output as 3 , This is the very first test case on codeforces also and codeforces showing output as 2 and as showing as wrong answer.

Please see here [Proof](https://codeforces.com/contest/489/submission/51827055) ,I never faced such kind of problem in competitive 
programming .
accepted solution [solution](https://codeforces.com/contest/489/submission/29310685)
There was also announcement related to this ques read below [here](https://codeforces.com/contest/489)

Comment: Please [edit] your question, to include [mcve], and all the information relevant to the question, in the question itself, as text, instead of external links.

Comment: Read this too: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: edited @AlgirdasPreidžius

Comment: You only check if you already seen a girl, shouldn't you do the same for the boys? and after you do that, you probably need to remove `break;`

Comment: @akashking So, what is the problem exactly? You state, that you get the output as `3`, and that it is correct output. If that is the case: what is the problem then? If some external site, gives you wrong output, did you run the most-up-to-date version of your code, there?

Comment: Count and value to set are backwards here: `memset(visited, sizeof(visited), false);`

Comment: But if I am running program in my ide I am getting exact output 3

Comment: I think it's undefined behavior because `memset(visited, sizeof(visited), false);` is wrong.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Yes brother I am using codeforces

Comment: why ? @ThomasSablik

Comment: brother please elaborate @ThomasSablik

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memset, count is last

Comment: @user4581301  In my Ide this program is showing correct output for the given testcases all 3

Comment: @akashking 1) I am not your brother. 2) The code you show here, [prints `3`](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1bh94dZoNqsTQ9Fs). And, because I fail to see any cases of Undefined behavior, if you are getting different answer on different environment, check if you are running the same code there. It's impossible to diagnose the problem, we cannot see (as in - you showing code, that produces "correct" output).

Comment: Please clarify: CodeForces expects a result of 2 and you compute 3?

Comment: But i added the link in proof you can see there
I am adding here https://codeforces.com/contest/489/submission/51827055

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius `if(!visited[j])` is undefined. `visited` is not initialized because the call `memset(visited, sizeof(visited), false);` is wrong. You are reading uninitialized variables.

Comment: sorry if you don't like that But that's how we indian's show respect to other who are helping us giving there precious time @AlgirdasPreidžius

Comment: @ThomasSablik I misread your intent. the memset is not UB, it does notihng.  Unitialized array, that's UB.

Comment: @ThomasSablik accepted thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a case of undefined behavior: `if(!visited[j])` is undefined. `visited` is not initialized because the call `memset(visited, sizeof(visited), false);` is wrong. You are reading uninitialized variables.

The declaration of `memset` is

```
void *memset( void *dest, int ch, size_t count );
```

You are writting 0 times the value 10000 into `visited`. On your machine this memory was filled with zeros. But on other machines there can be different values.

Comment: Is it also correct memset(visited,false,sizeof(visited))?
Because i changed to that and my answer got accepted

Comment: Recommend going a stop further and offering a better solution: `bool visited[10000] = {false};`

Comment: @user4581301 You should put this as an answer and explain why it is better

Comment: @Amadeus I voted to close as typo. Wouldn't be right to answer at this point.

Comment: Interesting side note: g++ 8.2 with `-pedantic -Wall -Wextra` warning flags set  emits a warning message for this. *warning: 'memset' used with constant zero length parameter; this could be due to transposed parameters* Compilers are getting smarter! Soon they will conquer the world!

Comment: @user4581301 I compiled with clang and got this warning. That's the way I found this problem. Compiler warnings are great. It is a pity many developers ignore them.